# wordpress image upload error and htaccess rule explanation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

To fix wordpress image upload error my hosting provider suggested to add the following rule in the htaccess file. I have added this rule and it fixed the issue. But can somebody explain me this rule or how this rule work?

```
SetEnv MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on a shared hosting. Your hosting provider might want to prevent abuse of CPU usage between each shared host. To prevent abuse they prevent you from running multi-thread tasks. When you load an image, Imagick (Which is an image processing tool) tries to use multi-thread to be as fast as possible.

Adding this rule, you tell Imagick to run only on a single thread and this prevent the previous error.